# cómo ir a la casilla anterior en css grid usando un bucle foreach?

Tags: php, css, css-grid-layout

estoy haciendo una galería de imágenes, que las muestro con un bucle foreach y ordenando las con css grid, el problema es que no puedo usar order, grid-column, grid-row o grid-area para volver atrás una casilla o moverla de posición hacia una anterior, por lo tanto si quiero agrandar una casilla o cualquier otra cosa con una seudo clase css por ejemplo :checked, solo me deja moverla hacia delante,
por qué pasa eso?

css

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'left right';
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns:450px;
    grid-row-gap:0px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    gap:0px;
}
.container input[type=checkbox].click:checked + .gallery {
    order:1;
    grid-area: left;
    grid-column: 1;
}
```

html de referencia desplegado con echo

```
foreach($data as $row){
    echo '
<input type="checkbox"id="click"class="click">
<label for="click"class="gallery">
  <div class="card"style="background-image: url(./images/gallery/'.$row["images"].');"
    <div class="texts">
        <h3 class="titlecard" style"::before">'.$row["title"]'</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
';
}
```

Comment: cual es el objetivo de un `foreach` y cual es el objetivo de un `echo`?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: ArcanisGK507 el objetivo de foreach: muetra la data de las tablas que tengo en MySQL por ejemplo las imágenes y los títulos de la galeria que los usuarios o el admin van subiendo.

El objetivo de echo: pone la data obtenida por foreach en el HTML que luego va ser estilizada por el CSS dándole esa forma de galeria

Comment: el echo no hace eso lo estás implementando mal en echo envía al buffer de salida los datos como cadenas... entonces no podrás hacer ningún cambio de esos datos por que ya están en el buffer de salida, yo te recomiendo meter en un array los datos y luego crear un nodo con los atributos css de cada elemento en el array... si llegas a un punto donde tengas que modificar el css del anterior podrías modificar lo con algo como esto: $output[$indicd-1] = $NewCSS;

Comment: al final puedes hacer un implode del array y imprimir con un solo echo todo el html d eun solo golpe y no enviarlo por partes.

Comment: ArcanisGK507 con nodo te refieres a DOMnode class https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domnode.php ? y como agrego los atributos css a un array, en la etiqueta html?

Comment: el nodo sería un índice en el array pero este sería multidimencional.

Comment: ArcanisGK507 cómo se agregaría css a ese array con atributos style=" " o con <style> en el <head> ?

Comment: ArcanisGK507 tienes el código o uno parecido, que aparezca en cualquier parte o sitio, para más o menos copiarlo y aprender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El CSS es igual no tiene que tocarlo, a lo mejor si debas agregar la regla que quieres pero no mas que eso; entonces el php y los slide deberias armarlo mas o menos asi:

```php
<?php
$bufferArr=[];

$imageSrc=[];

$count=0;

foreach($data as $row){
    $imageSrc[]=[
        'title' => $row["title"],
        'src' => $row["images"];
        'css' => 'color-1',
    ];
    //aqui es donde uso una condicion actual para saber/evaluar 
    //si debo ir a la casilla anterior a modificar el CSS que quiero aplicar.
    if($count!==0 && ($count % 2) == 0){ 
        //update color 2 del anterior
        $change = count($imageSrc)-1;
        $imageSrc[$change]['css']='color-2';
    }
    count++;
}


foreach($imageSrc as $key => $info){
    $bufferArr[]='<input type="checkbox"id="click"class="click">
        <label for="click"class="gallery">
          <div class="card"style="background-image: url(./images/gallery/'.$info["src"].');"
            <div class="texts">
                <h3 class="titlecard '.$info["css"].'" style"::before">'.$info["title"].'</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>';
}

$buffer = implode('',$bufferArr);

echo $buffer;
```

la idea es no enviar al buffer de salida el html hasta no haber terminado de procesarla informacion y armarla correctamente. poder aplicar css al elemento anterior, lo hago navegando con el indice del array; por eso veo la necesidad de implementar 2 foreach uno para armar los datos que se usaran en el html, en un paso previo y la segunda para levantar estructurar el html final que sera mostrada.